# Errors converting Array Php to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am having some troubles to convert a multidimensional PHP Array to JSON. I convert it with json_encode, but it gets null.

I am trying to develop an orgChart, the data is read from an CSV file and saved in an array. The layout and JS code is built to receive a JSON file, so I need it in that format.

This is an slice of the array, it contains 175 arrays within

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] =>  ELOTECH
            [cargo] => "" 
            [idcargo] => 1
            [pai] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [nome] => Departamento Pessoal
            [cargo] => 
            [idcargo] => 10
            [pai] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [nome] => Comercial
            [cargo] => 
            [idcargo] => 20
            [pai] => 1
        )
```

)

I am using json_encode to convert the array to JSON
OBS: *** $colab is the array's name fed by the CSV

```
$dados_json = json_encode($colab);
$fp = fopen("jsonOrgan.json", "w");
$write = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);
fclose($fp);
```

I need it to output on JSON as follow:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "cargo": "ELOTECH",
    "nome": "",
    "idcargo": 1,
    "pai": 0
}]
```

But it return null

Here is how I create the array from the CSV file.

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($save, 1000, ";")) {
    if ($linha++ == 0) {
        continue;
    }
 $colab[$linha] = [
                'id' => $line[0],
                'nome' => $line[1],
                'cargo' => $line[4],
                'idcargo' => $line[0],
                'pai' => $line[5],
            ];}
```

Comment: In English por favor

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for variable variables. Try `json_encode($$colab);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP edited. I voted to reopen.

Comment: Your array as been created like this { 1 : { data... } }  ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i've tried it, and got nothing

Comment: Please, put how it was been created on json_encode.

Comment: @RogerRussel, yes, it is created like this [ 1 => [['id'] => '1', [nome]=>'...'], 2 => [['id'] => '2', ['nome'] => ... ].

Comment: I know what is the problem, but you must accept my edit on your post first.

Comment: @RogerRussel i got it wrong my friend, sorry. The JSON isn't displaying anything, it gets NULL.

Comment: I will try just put hear. Your problem is because your array is indexed with numbers as key, you must change something like this $arr[$number]["nome"] = "asdasd" to something more like $arr[] = [ "nome" => "aasda", "id" => 123 ]

Comment: If it is given null then you must look for special chars which are not encoded was utf8.

Comment: You can see which error happened with this function "json_last_error_msg ()" usually null on json_encode are caused by wrong value on array, like "nome" => "Técnico", if it was not encoded with UTF8 you must encoded it with utf8_encode before use json_encode.

Comment: It's right Roger, i used utf8_encode and now it is converting to JSON, but now the problem is the one that you mentioned above.{"2":{"id":"1","nome":" ELOTECH","cargo":"","idcargo":"1","pai":0},"3":{"id":"10","nome":"Departamento Pessoal","cargo":"","idcargo":"10","pai":"1"}

Comment: Change your array creation from something like this $arr[$number] = [ "id" => 123123 ] to $arr[] = [ "id" => 123123 ], because PHP thinks that numbers are especific keys and not only index, if it was not possible, you will need reindex your array with something like this: $newArray = [] ;  foreach ( $arr as $a )  $newArray[] = $a;

Comment: I will edit the post showing how I create the array

Comment: @RogerRussel You saved my life, my friend. After fixing the uft8_encode, I followed as you told me, and created the array $colab[] => [], and now the JSON is the way i needed. Thank you. I don't have enough words to show you my gratitude.

Comment: @RogerRussel could/should post an answer for this and to close the question properly.

Comment: Do _not_ use `utf8_encode()`, it is not some magical function that knows what your input is and translates it to UTF8, it does absolutely nothing but assume ISO-8859-1 [western european] input and translates input bytes according to that translation. If your input is encoded in literally _anything_ else [including UTF8] this function will silently corrupt your data. Use something like [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [`iconv()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) and properly specify your input/output encodings.

Comment: @Sammitch thank you for the information, i didn't know that. I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: @JeanLima you are welcome.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I was running late for a job interview and today it has already responded but thats is ok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Roger Russel's instructions, my problem got solved.

The JSON was getting NULL because of the encoding. 
I used the **uft8_encode** and solved this problem.
Then i changed the array creation to fit the pattern that I need the JSON file to be.

I was creating the Array Using a counter as index, as follow:

```
$colab[$linha] = [
                'id' => $line[0],
                'nome' => $line[1],
                'cargo' => $line[4],
                'idcargo' => $line[0],
                'pai' => $line[5],
            ]
```

Then changed it to be created without passing the index:

```
$colab[] = [
                    'id' => $line[0],
                    'nome' => $line[1],
                    'cargo' => $line[4],
                    'idcargo' => $line[0],
                    'pai' => $line[5],
                ]
```

And that's it, my problem was solved!

Thank you!

Comment: Good job finding the problem and solution on your own then sharing it for others, keep up the good work :)

Comment: It wasn't on my own, @Roger Russel made all the job

Comment: One is glad to be of service